# Sorted Dictionary - C#

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, enums, logic, sorteddictionary

I'm trying to figure out how to create a sorted dictionary where the key is sorted in a non-alphabetical manner.  Is there a way I can define the way I want it to sort?

For example, the keys might be in order like the following:

```
AAA1X
AAB1Y
AAC1Y
AAA2X
AAB2Y
AAC2X
```

Although the first three letters are alphabetical, if I sort as is it will lump them in the wrong order (due to the number). Also note, that there is either a X or Y at the end.  In the code, there will only ever be an X or a Y.

Even if I can write an enumeration for the ordering of all possible combinations I'd be willing to do that as well, but I'm not sure how I can use the sorted dictionary and an enumeration...

I know this is a bit vague, but any help would be much appreciated!

Cheers!

Comment: You can implement IDictionary yourself and sort however you want.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

One of the constructors for `SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>` takes an `IComparer<TKey>`, where you can specify a custom comparer class that the dictionary will use for sorting.

```
public class CustomComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    public int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        // do your own comparison however you like; return a negative value
        // to indicate that x < y, a positive value to indicate that x > y,
        // or 0 to indicate that they are equal.
    }
}

...

SortedDictionary<string, object> dict = 
              new SortedDictionary<string, object>(new CustomComparer());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can :

Create a class that encapsulates those keys and override the == operator, `Object.Equals` method and the `Object.GetHashCode` method. Also have the class implement the [IComparable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d7sx9hd.aspx) interface such that the rules for equality will automatically sort your keys the right way. Now you can simply place those keys in a [SortedDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c.aspx) or [SortedList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132319.aspx) and it will automatically sort the way you want.

**OR**

Implement an [IComparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ehhxeaf.aspx) object that compares those strings the way you want, and specify the IComparer when constructing a [SortedDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c.aspx)or [SortedList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132319.aspx).

Comment: Overloading the `==` operator won't do anything (note that you can *overload* operators, *not override*, as operators are not polymorphic).

Comment: actually, SortedDictionary/SortedList don't make any use GetHashCode/Equals methods. In order to make your object able to be sorted, it has to implement `IComparable<YourType>`

Comment: You're correct on the terminology. I edited my original answer. For the first approach, the encapsulating class has to implement the IComparable<T> interface. If keynesiancross is wading into that territory it's good to be thorough and override Equals and GetHashCode. He should also overload == since he wants the encompassing class to act like a string. i.e. obj_a == obj_b  if they have the same string content.